# Espresso Instrumentation Test works on Emulator but hangs on Android Device

Tags: android, android-espresso

Below, is a simple test I wrote using the Espresso Instrument Testing Framework.

```
MainActivity mActivity;

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);


@Before
public void beforeClass() {
    setMasterPolicyTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    setIdlingResourceTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void basicInstrumentationTestForTitle() throws Exception {

    UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    uiDevice.wakeUp();
    mActivity = mActivityRule.getActivity();

    onView(withId(R.id.title)).check(matches(withText("Title")));
}
```

Now this test executes fine when I run it on an Android Emulator (Nexus S API 23) as provided by Android Studio. However, when I run the same test on an android device, I get the following error.

```
    android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 85 iterations over 45 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed ASYNC_TASKS_HAVE_IDLED.
    at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
    at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
    at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
    at activities.ActivityInstrumentationTest.basicInstrumentationTestForTitle(ActivityInstrumentationTest.java:71)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
    at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1867)
```

For reference, I have turned off animation options on the test device.

testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

Can someone please help to solve this? Also if possible please explain how it worked on the emulator but not on the actual device.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am facing a similar issue